# Submiting a form using JavaScript in Django is not working

Tags: javascript, django

### I try to submit a form by Javascript in Django.

The form is **working** 
The Javascript is **working** 
The submit() function is **not working**.

**My testing HTML code:**

```
<form method="post" id='testForm' action="www.google.com">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a onclick="onDeleteButtonClick()" href="">Delete</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**My testing Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDeleteButtonClick(){
        console.log("before");
        document.getElementById("testForm").submit();
        console.log("after");
    }
</script>
```

### 3 Results:

This part of the web page looks like this:
[web page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ufM.png)
Really simple

**A** When I click the Submit button:
It is **working**, the form is been submit.

**B** When I click the delete link:
It is **not working**. 
The log in Javascript works, I can see "before" and "after" in the console.

**C** I also test this on a normal web page (without Django framework), the Submit button, and the Delete link is **all working**.
So I think it must be something related to Django.

If anyone knows why this happened, please let me know~ Thank you!